# Xcode 7 not recognizing String extension methods (error until I build)

Tags: xcode

I have have a swift file with the following code:

```
extension String {

    //getting char and substrings
    subscript(integerIndex: Int) -> Character {
        let index = self.startIndex.advancedBy(integerIndex)
        return self[index]
    }

    subscript(integerRange: Range<Int>) -> String {
        let start = self.startIndex.advancedBy(integerRange.startIndex)
        let end = self.startIndex.advancedBy(integerRange.endIndex)
        let range = start..<end
        return self[range]
    }

}
```

When I try to use the extension

```
let str = "Hello World!"
let char = str[0]
```

I get the following error:
`'subscript' is unavailable: cannot subscript String with an Int, see [...]`
But when I run the project, or build it the error goes away and builds successfully. The error returns when I start typing again. It's not a huge deal, but it does bother me seeing errors.

Thanks!

Comment: This code works good for me in Xcode 7.2 (7C46l). There are no errors/warnings.

Comment: hmmm I'm on 7.1 didn't notice. No updates available on the AppStore either. (I'm in Canada) maybe that's why?

Comment: The latest release is 7.1, but you can download 7.2 beta here: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/

Comment: Have you tried restarting Xcode / cleaning project? I tested this code in Xcode 7.1 playground and it works.

Comment: Haven't tried on a playground, but I have tried restarting Xcode. Currently downloading 7.2 beta, will report back when I try on 7.2

Comment: Xcode 7.2 beta fixed my issue, thanks!